# jelly fin base URL doesn't work for my project

Tags: sqlite, jellyfin

I have jelly fin base URL and a token. I don't know where I should set them to get data.
the project is connected to jelly fin, I just wanna change base URL.
I installed SQL lite editor in my VS code and I have columns like jelly fin base URL and others...

I've added base URL and token. it doesn't work.